# Why does auto focus on my new Fuji X100F keep moving while I have the shutter button held halfway?

Tags: autofocus, focus, focus-motor, continuous-autofocus, fujifilm-x100

I just bought a Fuji x100f and right out of the box I notice something with the autofocus (maybe it's normal and I just need to understand the camera). When you push the shutter button half way and the camera focus automatically, the lens doesn't stop moving... like it's always trying to focus. I can see the green box in the viewfinder, meaning that the subject is in focus, but the lens continuous to move, like trying to focus, and you can hear and feel the motors working. It doesn't stop.

I'm not focusing on a moving subject, so I would think that the camera would focus my subject and stop working.

Is this a normal behaviour in this camera? It's some kind of mode that I could turn off?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Are you sure the noise you hear is from focusing rather than image stabilization?

Comment: The X100F has no stabilization.

Comment: What are you trying to focus on? Is it a high-contrast object that the AF system can easily detect? Is it farther away than the minimum focus distance? Is the camera on AF-C instead of AF-S?

Answer (score 5):

There is a small black slider on the side opposite the camera grip. It has 3 positions. If you slide it to the bottom it will be in AF-S mode which stops focusing as soon as autofocus locks after you press the shutter-release halfway. It is hard to see but that is number 20 in the diagram below:

[image]

It sounds like your camera has the switch in the middle which is the AF-C position. That makes the camera continuously focus until the shutter is released. For completeness, the topmost position is Manual Focus mode.

Comment: I had the same problem and was even wondering if my newly purchased X100F was faulty... It was indeed as simple as sliding the side-button to AF-S. Thank you ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it baffled me. The camera kept focusing even when it was “idling”. Turns out I had set “Pre Focus” to “on”. Do you have “Pre Focus” turned on? If yes, turn it off. That stopped my camera from trying to continuously focus. (Also set to AF-S as described above)